# MUI CSS: How to control image?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I have a MUI React Component with a Card wrapping img and buttons

```
<Card key={index} className="xl:w-[350px] w-[310px] max-h-[450px]">
  <img src={meme.url} className="center bg-cover" alt="" />
  <Box className="h-[72px] flex items-center justify-between px-4">
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
      <Button startIcon={<ThumbUpIcon />}>{meme.likes}</Button>
      <Button startIcon={<VisibilityIcon />}>{meme.views}</Button>
    </Stack>
    <Button className="btn colorBtn">Remix</Button>
  </Box>
</Card>
```

The Image is covering the card like
[Image card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpzc.png)

How can I control the image so that it doesnt overflow the card?
How can I achieve consistency with image size relative to the card? or just in general?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp , and if you need to override an MUI style https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because bottom Box have 72px height, so image height should be `calc(100% - 72px)`, you also need set `w-full object-cover` to image

```
<Card
    key={index}
    className="max-h-[450px] w-[310px] xl:w-[350px]"
>
    <img
        style={{ height: `calc(100% - 72px)` }}
        src={meme.url}
        className="center w-full bg-cover object-cover"
        alt=""
    />
    <Box className="flex h-[72px] items-center justify-between px-4">
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
            <Button startIcon={<ThumbUpIcon />}>
                {meme.likes}
            </Button>
            <Button startIcon={<VisibilityIcon />}>
                {meme.views}
            </Button>
        </Stack>
        <Button className="btn colorBtn">Remix</Button>
    </Box>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) css property for your `img` element:

```
<img
  src={meme.url}
  className="center 
  bg-cover"
  alt=""
  sx={{ objectFit: "contain" }}
/>;
```